# Jquery Dropdown menu with thumbnail Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

how to make or any plugin available like this type of dropdown menu http://www.vivantabytaj.com (small images inside dropdown menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just CSS and you could use jQuery if you wanted but most of your request can be handled by CSS. The only thing you may want to use jQuery for is animation effects.

So I would do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">some link</a>
          <ul>
              <li>
                 <img arc="someimage.jpg" />
                 <p>some text you want to display</p>
              </ul>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav ul ul { display: none; }
.nav img { float: left; }
.nav p { float: right; }
```

JQuery

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function(){
   $( this ).children("ul").slideToggle(500);
});
```

You would probably want to constrain the images size as well by defining image width or height or both but this would be a good starting point. Also be sure to include the jQuery library.

Comment: @Jure Ravlic - Theres not error in the syntax if you look at the code you'll see that the ".nav li" has a onclick listener applied to it and that you target "this" the .nav li then its child "ul" which will display that child ul so I am not sure what you're talking about wrong syntax?

Did you look at his example at all or read his remarks? The plugin you pointed him to does not do what he wants?

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Bird 
There's a mistake in sintax on second level of ul tag. (should be comment).

You could also use this plugin to automate this: [Hover Flow Plugin](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/)

It's very easy to use. You just have to add some class to main ul tag to trigger the plugin. Read Doc.

Comment: Theres not error in the syntax if you look at the code you'll see that the ".nav li" has a onclick listener applied to it and that you target "this" the .nav li then its child "ul" which will display that child ul so I am not sure what you're talking about wrong syntax? Did you look at his example at all or read his remarks? The plugin you pointed him to does not do what he wants?

Comment: @Tom Bird `<li>`  has no end tag. Plugin does the trick, he wanted dropdown on hover not on click (regarding the example).It is also a good solution because in this plugin, hovers are not being cached. That means that when you hover fast ten times on one and on the other menu, the hovers are being cached and will try to execute that ten times, while in Hover Plugin they will only execute only one time.

Comment: Example with sub menus is located in the right sidebar under  [Sub Menu Test Page](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/submenus.html) .The second one has hide/show effect like @Preethu Alex wanted in his [example](http://www.vivantabytaj.com)